# How to remove all conflicting characters between latin1 and utf-8 using python?

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii

I call open(file, "r") and read some lines in Python. This gives me:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If I add 'utf-8', I get:

```
'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 28-29: invalid continuation byte
```

If I add 'ISO-8859-1', I get no errors but a line is read like this:

```
2890 ready to try Arghï¿½ Fantasy Surfer Carnageï¿½ Dane, Marlon &amp; Nat C all out!  #fantasysurfer
```

As you can see there are some extra characters, which probably come from emojis or something... (These are tweets)..

What is the best approach to clean these lines up?

I would like to remove all the extraneous elements... I would like the strings to have only numbers, letters, and common symbols ?!>.;, etc...

Note: I don't care about the html entities, since I replace those in another function. I am talking about the weird Argh**ï¿½** Carnage**ï¿½** elements.

In general, these are causing issues with the encoding.

Comment: I am using that one... (ISO-8859-1)

Comment: Can't you find out what encoding has been used for the file originally?

Comment: I can't that is why I tried Latin1 :(

Comment: Sorry, I  just saw utf-8, where did the data come from?

Comment: Your data actually is UTF-8. Can you provide the code you use to read it? And maybe copy-paste some data as well?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try first use decode and then encode:

```
u"text".decode('latin-1').encode('utf-8')
```

Or try open file with codecs:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open('file', encoding="your coding")
```

Your problem is either opening the file in wrong encoding, or you incorrectly identify the character encoding.

Also if you get text in ASCII use it:

```
'abc'.decode('ascii')
```

or

```
unicode('abc', 'ascii')
```

Comment: This worked, I made it ascii, it removed those weird chars.

Comment: `u"text".decode('latin-1')` that's mixed up. You encode *from* unicode and you decode *to* unicode.

Comment: I led the coding just for an example. I don't know the original text and I think topicstarter'll be able to choose.

Answer (score 1):

first, ensure that you especified the rigth codification at the first line in the python file.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Second, you can use the library codecs specifying the desired codification:

```
import codecs
fich_in = codecs.open(filename,'r', encoding='utf-8')
```

Third, you can to ignore all the wrong characters using:

```
TEXT.encode('utf-8', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
```

could help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).